# File generated by logger not found in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, file, logging, dockerfile

I am running a node server and using a file logger in server which prints all logs in a log file rather than printing it on console.

Now everthings works fine on local, files are being created.

But now i am trying to run the same thing in docker and tried to look inside the container to check whether the files are being created or not. using
`docker exec -it <container_id> bash` but didn't found any log file there.

Logs generated are only visible through `docker logs` command.

Am i looking at the wrong place or am i doing anything wrong here.

Edit
Here's the DockerFile for the same

```
FROM node:14

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir /temp
WORKDIR /app
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

COPY package*.json ./

RUN node --version && npm -v
RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Are you creating the log inside the container or have you mount a volume in your docker run to store the file in the host? Docker logs are usually stored in /var/lib/docker/containers by default.

Comment: i am trying to store logs file in directory where server's start command is executed which i think is the app directory in container according to Dockerfile ( Let me paste the Dockerfile too ). still didn't found anything inside it